# Sourcemap is likely to be incorrect: a plugin (terser) was used to transform files, but didn't generate a sourcemap for the transformation

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, rollupjs, terser

I'm trying to upgrade mui, rollup, nodejs and npm but encountered this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVLKz.png)

[tsconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgHbb.png)

all packages are in their latest version

tried these:
[Rollup is not generating typescript sourcemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218218/rollup-is-not-generating-typescript-sourcemap)
[How to get rid of the "@rollup/plugin-typescript: Rollup 'sourcemap' option must be set to generate source maps." warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128597/how-to-get-rid-of-the-rollup-plugin-typescript-rollup-sourcemap-option-must)
rollup-plugin-sourcemaps

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.